# Basic algebra but can't get answer that fits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2 p+ m= 135$ whereas
$p + 2m = 120$
And $p+ m+ a = 100$ 
Find $a$.

Basic algebra but can't get sensible answer (:

Comment: Hint: look at your first two equalities. What do you get if you add them?

Answer (score 9):

After adding equality $1$ and equality $2$, we get the following:$$3m + 3p = 255$$We may divide both sides by $3$ to get,$$m + p = 85  $$Since we already have $m + p  = 85 $, we see that $m  + p + a$ can be written as $85 + a$(substituting $m + p$ with $85$).

We are left with the equation:$$ 85 + a = 100$$Clearly, $a = 15$

Comment: good job ,in math stackexchange there are very few questions that 12 years child can deal with.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was comparatively an _easy_ problem, thus making me have a go at it.